# Given a list, find Association from index to value

Tags: associations

I have a list

```
list = {"a","b","c",…}
```

and I want the association

```
<| 1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", … |>
```

This seems like the sort of thing there would be a built-in function for, but I haven't been able to find one.

I could do this using

```
list // AssociationThread[Range @ Length[#], #] &
```

or

```
Association@MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, list]
```

or

```
AssociationMap[list[[#]]&, Range @ Length[list]]
```

but these are all rather unwieldy. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think that there is a better way. These seem quite simple to me.  `AssociationThread[Range@Length[list] -> list]` is likely the fastest.

Comment: I keep a shorthand for `Range@*Length` because I use it so often; that would at least shorten your code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - In this case, `Range@Length@list` is one character shorter than `Range@*Length@list`

Comment: @Stephan Powell For nested lists you could do `l = {"a", {"b", "c"}}; a = <||>;
MapIndexed[AssociateTo[a, #2 -> #1] &, l, {-1}];`